# Why do I get a "Cannot read property 'click' of null error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Inside the `BODY` tag:

```
<asp:Panel ID="nmSearch" CssClass="searchBox" runat="server" DefaultButton="HiddenSearchNM">
    <input type="text" runat="server" value="" placeholder="Search" id="searchB" class="styledTB searchB floatLeft" />
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" onclick="SearchNMClick();" title="Search" class="styledBtnSearch searchAnchor floatLeft defaultLinks">
        <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/searchWhite.png" CssClass="searchImg" runat="server" ToolTip="Search" AlternateText="Search" />
    </a>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="HiddenSearchNM" runat="server" CssClass="hideContent" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Inside the `HEAD` tag:

```
<script>
function SearchNMClick() {
    document.getElementById('HiddenSearchNM').click();
}
</script>
```

I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
SearchNMClick
onclick
```

C# code behind which will fire off a search page from either `Enter` or click:

```
protected void HiddenSearchNM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("SEARCH NM");
        strSMain = searchB.Value;
        Response.Redirect("results.aspx?searchtext=" + strSMain +"&folderid=0&searchfor=all&orderby=title&orderdirection=ascending");
    }
```

But when I hit enter while in the textbox or the button click, I get the error above.

How do I resolve the error.

So weird, when I check the HTML source I see this (not sure why the ID is being changed):

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$CUSTOM_Area_Top$HiddenSearchNM" id="ctl00_CUSTOM_Area_Top_HiddenSearchNM" class="hideContent" ClientIDMode="Static" src="" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CUSTOM_Area_Top$HiddenSearchNM&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

Comment: ASP changes the id value for you, so you have to use an API to get the correct string to use.

Comment: I have `ClientIDMode='static'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change you JS function to:

```
function SearchNMClick() {
    document.getElementById('<%# HiddenSearchNM.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Page` directive to set static ids

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="static" %>
```

That should work with your id selector.

Also, check your rendered HTML for your `ImageButton`. If everything is setup correctly, it should preserve the `ID`.

Comment: Put the directive on the `Page`. I see ASP.NET is just rendering junk HTML when you set it at the control level.

Comment: That is a good suggestion except, some of the other vendor control is using the regular ASP ID so not going to work. I am wondering if I can use ClientID in javascript

Comment: Of course! `document.querySelector('[ClientID=HiddenSearchNM]')`

Comment: Where would I add that?