# Passing Value from Modal1 to another Modal2 Using Javascript ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to get/pass value from Modal1 to Modal2. I have a modal1 that opens modal2 for getting value that needed in Modal1. I always get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null". I triple check my ID.

```
function ViewPM(field1) {
    window.top.document.getElementById("tbProjectPM").value = field1;
    document.getElementById("btnClosePM").click();
}
```

Both window.top.document.getElementById and document.getElementById not working.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check actual ID assigned to respective elements. If you're using standard ASPX page and both elements are server controls, use `ClientID` property of the controls:

```
function ViewPM(field1) {
    window.top.document.getElementById("<%= tbProjectPM.ClientID %>").value = field1;
    document.getElementById("<%= btnClosePM.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

Or if you don't want auto-generated IDs, try setting `ClientIDMode` property to `static` either in page level or each controls that used in `document.getElementById()`:

**Page level**

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

**Control level**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClosePM" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ...>
</asp:Button>
```

Related issue:

[Why do I get a "Cannot read property 'click' of null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490678/why-do-i-get-a-cannot-read-property-click-of-null-error)

Comment: its still not working. I triple check my ID but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I already know how.

```
function ViewPM(field1) {
    parent.document.getElementById("tbProjectPM").value = field1;
    parent.document.getElementById("btnClosePM").click();
}
```

To get values modal1 from another modal2 use parent keyword.

Here's a link 
https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe-iframe.php